# DDD object creation design

Tags: wcf, architecture, dns, domain-driven-design

I'm developing a server side application based on DDD.

My application service (wcf layer) has a method which received an XML from the client.
This XML needs to be processed and finally transformed into an object.

In such a case, where's the best place to put the data transformation logic?
Inside the domain model?

Example:

```
void OnRequestArrived(string xml)
{
   ItemRequest request = ItemRequest.New(xml);
}
```

or in a separate domain service?

```
void OnRequestArrived(string xml)
{
  ItemRequest request = _mappingService.Map(xml);
}
```

The ItemRequest object is then the main domain model for the business flow..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This responsibility belongs to the WCF service. In DDD terms, this is the anti-corruption layer - it maps external models to the domain model at hand. The domain model should be protected from external services as much as possible.

Sometimes it can be convenient to break this single WCF service into two - an application service and a WCF-specific [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which would *adapt* the application service to the WCF framework. This is based on the [Hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture). The application service knows nothing about WCF or serialization formats. The WCF adapter service handles this and other serialization concerns. This can be useful for two reasons. First it keeps your application service clean and focused on its responsibility - the orchestration of domain objects, repositories and other services to implement domain use cases. Second, it allows the same application service to be called from different adapters.